# Only create classes with XJCFacade when schema changes

Tags: java, ant, xsd

```
<target name="buildBbastJarFromXsd">
    <echo message="Generating jar from xsd for RestService"/>
    <java classname="com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.XJCFacade">
        <arg value="-d" />
        <arg value="${dev.location}"/>
        <arg "${dev.location}/path/dev.xsd" />
    </java>
    <javac srcdir="${dev.location}" destdir="${dev.location}"
        debug="on" includeantruntime="false"
    >
        <classpath refid="dev.classpath"/>
    </javac>
    <jar
        destfile="${dev.location}/WebContent/WEB-INF/rest.jar"
        basedir="${bbct.location}"
        includes="**/*.class"
    />
</target>
```

How do I edit the above Ant task in build.xml to make sure that the above scripts of java(XJCFacade) run only if the xsd-named dev.xsd gets modified?

And I also want to make sure that javac and jar run ONLY if the java(XJCFacade) runs.